# Using nearest neighbour with conditional field using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, proximity

I'm using QGIS 3.6

I have a point layer with the 84000 animal positions on a fence on varying dates.

I would like to obtain the nearest other animal to each animal point, on the condition the Date is the same. I have been able to add the nearest animal ID and its distance, but only by one date selection at a time.

Can I select all to do it at the same time, but on the condition the date matches?

I tried using a python code base on a different question but for QGIS 2.18 and I can't adapt it for more recent versions... maybe someone else can, link below for reference.

[Finding closest segment to point which contains same attribute using NNJoin plugin of QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250528/find-the-closest-segment-to-a-point-which-contains-the-same-attribute)